# Binary Search can sort?

Tags: c++

Can I sort an array using Binary search? Or do I have to separately do another form of a sorting algorithm and then do a Binary Search to find a certain value input by a user?

The assignment given

> **Binary Search (C++)**
>
> ```
> 5  1  15  6  4  8  2  10  13  9
> ```
>
> Sort these numbers using binary search and locate the 6th and the 9th index.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to ask your professor how this was meant?

Comment: doing a binary search requires a pre-sorted input array. I think you misunderstood.

Comment: For `std::set` and `std::map`, binary search is used for every insertion, which results in an always sorted container. Maybe, this is what your professor addressed...

Comment: `Sort these numbers using binary search` does not make sense on its own. Plain vanilla binary search does not modify the array being searched (it requires the array to already be sorted).

Comment: the point of the exercise is to train what you covered in class. We can guess but it might not be what your prof expects, eventually you have to ask them to be sure you understand the task correctly

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yeah that's what I think too.  A really misleading task he gave us.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  And to make matters worst he dropped classes and made us do self-paced research. He hasn't had classes with us for the last 4 weeks.

Comment: another student of the same class asked similar question yesterday (or was it you?). Thats a problem you have to adress, maybe complain on a higher level, but I am afraid its not something we can offer much help with. I get payed to solve unclear tasks, but I don't think they have a place in teaching.

Comment: anyhow, binary insertion sort seems to be the only reasonable

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Oh wow really? Good to know I ain't the only one who's confused. So yeah Binary insertion sort would be the way to go. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called binary insertion sort where you create a new list which is populated using binary search to know where to put each element to get a sorted list as result.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-insertion-sort/

Comment: the code in the link is C code, maybe you can find a better reference for C++

Comment: the link should point out the principle of the algorithm. if this is for a class exercise it is maybe even better to have the solution only in other languages to learn how it works and then do it on your own in the target language.

Comment: then still, the link does not have much explanation. How about this instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: i agree this could be useful too. but add the hint that this is not "binary" insertion sort